# What does "VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState contains the configuration per attached framebuffer" mean?

Tags: vulkan

I read the [Color blending](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Fixed_functions#:%7E:text=depth%20buffering%20chapter.-,Color%20blending,-After%20a%20fragment) Vulkan tutorial.

and this page says :

> The first struct, VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState contains the configuration per attached framebuffer and the second struct, VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo contains the global color blending settings.In our case we only have one framebuffer

> The second structure references the array of structures for all of the framebuffers

However, in the [Framebuffers](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Framebuffers) chapter, as many framebuffers as the number of imageView were created.

But the code associated with it is the same.

And per-framebuffer struct no framebuffer-related members.

How do one attach a color blend attachment to a framebuffer?

My guess is that it is automatically attached via VkFramebufferCreateInfo::pAttachments when recording the commands (i.e. when the render pass begins), am I right?

or rather via VkSubpassDescription::pColorAttachments ?

because [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html) say:

> The value of attachmentCount must be greater than the index of all color attachments that are not VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED in VkSubpassDescription::pColorAttachments or VkSubpassDescription2::pColorAttachments for the subpass in which this pipeline is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, tutorials do not use proper wording. This is one of those times.

Recall that a pipeline is built against a specific subpass of a specific render pass. Also recall that subpasses have a list of (among other things) color attachments that represent the render targets for rendering operations in that subpass.

What the tutorial *means* is that `VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState` defines the blend state for a particular attachment in the subpass designated by the pipeline. The array of `VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState` structs mirrors the array of color attachments used in the subpass the pipeline is being built for. So the third element of `VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo::pAttachments` corresponds to the third element in `VkSubpassDescription::pColorAttachments` for the subpass the pipeline is being built for.

For some reason, this tutorial refers to these attachments as "attached framebuffer," as this is *absolutely* the wrong term to use. They're just attachments.

Framebuffers provide the images that will be used as attachments when you begin a render pass. But the pipeline doesn't (really) care what image object you use. It cares about what color attachment in the subpass you're talking about.